# Wrong encoding of quotation marks in write_csv()

Tags: r, encoding, readr

Is there a way to preserve the encoding of the double quotation marks in `readr::write_csv()`?

In something as simple as:

```
str <- tibble(x='“ABC”')
readr::write_csv(str,'a.csv')
```

The double quotation marks get turned into weird symbols:
[image]

Comment: The quotation used in the sample data must be quotation marks interpreted as something else in R - I get the same issue if I copy and paste your sample data, but if you simply delete the quotes then add them back in, it exports fine

Comment: This is due to Excel not recognizing the data as UTF-8, it's not (really) an R issue. Use `readr::write_excel_csv()` to include a BOM so Excel recognises the encoding.